# How to fix "IndexError: string index out of range" error in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I recently started learning Python from a MOOC on Coursera. I'm trying to write a while loop that starts at the last character in the string and works its way backwards to the first character in the string, printing each letter on a separate line, except backwards.

I have written the code which is giving me the desired output but it's also giving me an error

> "IndexError: string index out of range"

```
index = 0
fruit = "potato"
while index <= len(fruit) :
    index = index - 1
    letter = fruit[index] 
    print(letter)
```

> ```
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "strings_01.py", line 8, in <module>
>         letter = fruit[index]
>     IndexError: string index out of range
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm sorry if the above code looks stupid, I've just recently started to learn. I tried your recommendation and it doesn't work. It gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different `while` loop condition:

```
index = 0
fruit = "potato"
while abs(index) < len(fruit):
    index = index - 1
    letter = fruit[index] 
    print(letter)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly fine without any errors. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Honestly, I prefer my answer since it doesn't need the `abs()` function call at every iteration.

Comment: @PrashantGonga Happy to help :P

Comment: @alec_djinn Well, okay, but OP preferred mine, also self-advertising isn't good

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Of course, it's just for the sake of learning, there are better ways to do that in Python.

```
fruit = "potato"
index = len(fruit) -1 #Python indexes starts from 0!
while index >= 0 :
    letter = fruit[index]
    print(letter)
    index -= 1 #decrease at the END of the loop!
```

Output:

```
o
t
a
t
o
p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruit = "potato"
index = len(fruit)
while index > 0 :
    index = index - 1
    letter = fruit[index] 
    print(letter)
```

Comment: This code runs without any error but the output doesn't seem to be correct. Here is the output I've got.

o
t
a
t
o
p
o

There is an extra "o" added to the output at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> fruit = "potato"
>>> fruit = fruit[::-1]
>>> fruit
'otatop'
>>> for letter in fruit:
...     print(letter)
...
o
t
a
t
o
p
```

Alternatively with `while loop`:

```
>>> fruit = "potato"
>>> fruit = fruit[::-1]
>>> fruit
'otatop'
>>>  index = 0
>>> while index < len(fruit):
...     print(fruit[index])
...     index+=1
...
o
t
a
t
o
p
```

Comment: The OP wants to use a while loop to do that.

Comment: @alec_djinn still what is the issue if I use `for`. But I will respect your comment and will edit answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I need to write this code only using while loop

Comment: @PrashantGonga I have added the answer with while loop.

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou The issue is that the OP asked a solution involving a while-loop and you are answering with a for-loop. So, technically, it's a wrong answer. The code will work, but the answer doesn't fit the specs of the question.

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou You while-loop is wrong. Run it to check that the expected output is indeed the one you posted.

Comment: @alec_djinn I have said I will add the loop point you can see I have reverse the string already in the above answer. I will add that part again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for

```
index = 0
fruit = "potato"
while index > -(len(fruit)) :
    index = index - 1
    letter = fruit[index]
    print(letter)
```